# Angular 2: Error: src/app/mage/mage.component.ts (19,98): ',' expected.) app/mage/mage.component.ts (19,100): Cannot find name 'response'.)

Tags: angular, service

I have this error while I am trying to hook an angular 2 service to another Angular 2 component:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/mage/mage.component.ts
Module build failed: Error: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/angular2/ng2/src/app/mage/mage.component.ts (19,98): ',' expected.)
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/angular2/ng2/src/app/mage/mage.component.ts (19,100): Cannot find name 'response'.)
```

Why is this happening? If possible, try to help me, and don't downvote, because this is my second day with Angular 2, I am very much a noob with Angular 2. I kindly ask this because my last Angular 2 question was killed by downvoting, and went into negative score. Thank you for not negative downvoting me to the depths of hell :)

This is mage.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MageService } from './mage.service';
import { OrdersStats } from './orders.stats';
import { OrderStatusStat} from './order.status.stat';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-mage',
  templateUrl: './mage.component.html',
  styleUrls:['./mage.component.css']
})
export class MageComponent {

  ordersStatistics:OrdersStats; 

  constructor(private mageService: MageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.mageService.getMagentoData().subscribe(response => <OrdersStats>this.ordersStatistics = response);
  }
}
```

This is orders.stats.ts:

```
export class OrdersStats {

    total:number;
    orderStatusesStats:OrderStatusStat[];
}
```

This is mage.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { OrderStatusStat } from './order.status.stat';
import { OrdersStats } from './orders.stats';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MageService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getMagentoData() {
      return this.http.get("http://localhost:80/angular2/ng2/middleware/MiddleWare.php")
      .map(response => <OrdersStats>response.json().data);
  }

}
```

This is orders.status.stat.ts:

```
export class OrderStatusStat {

    status:string; //Name of the status
    count:number; //How many orders with this status
    totalAmount:number; //Total amount of all orders with this status

}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code from `mage.component.ts`?

Comment: @Riscie code added.

Comment: this line: `this.mageService.getMagentoData().subscribe(response => <OrdersStats>this.ordersStatistics = response);` can not be written like you did. Try `this.mageService.getMagentoData().subscribe(response => {<OrdersStats>this.ordersStatistics = response});` (No implicit return)

Comment: @Riscie wrapping the code <OrdersStats>this.ordersStatistics = response}); in curly braces didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use casting in the short hand style of the arrow function, you should write it like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.mageService.getMagentoData().subscribe((response) => {
        this.ordersStatistics = <OrdersStats>response;
   });      
}
```